# How to save output of "watch" to file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to run a command every 60 seconds, and save the output to a logfile.
I know I can print to console by

```
watch -n 60 <mycommand>
```

But what if I want to save it to a file as well as print to console?

Comment: Already solved here: http://superuser.com/questions/297283/store-the-output-of-date-and-watch-command-to-a-file

Comment: Use tee http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Watch is designed to run in a console window. Printing its output to file is inconvenient, because of the extensive amount of unprintable formatting characters.

You can try this without watch, if the exact 60 seconds is not an issue:

```
 while <some condition>
 do
     <mycommand> 2>&1 | tee -a /path/to/logfile
     sleep 60
 done
```

This saves the output to a log file and shows it on console as well.

Comment: You can run the command as a background process so that it starts every 60 seconds, rather than 60 seconds after it last completed.

Comment: Yepp, you're right. You can add it to your crontab as well like this:
"* * * * * /path/to/mycommand 2>&1 | /path/to/tee -a /path/to/logfile"
Although this won't work, if you want to run it more frequently than once in every 60 seconds.

Comment: Why the output of the file still looks weird for me? It has stuff like this ```[24;80H[1;74H20[24;80H[1;75H1[24;80H[1;75H2[24;80H```

Answer (score 5):

try it:

```
while true
do
    watch -n 60 <command> 2>&1 | tee -a logfile
done
```

I use `tee` so that you can see the output on your terminal as well as capture it in your log.

Comment: This doesn't result in usable output as the resulting file is filed with terminal emulator control codes.

Comment: Is there a way to make a usable output ? without the terminal stuff? please