# How to store output of "watch" to a file?

Tags: linux, shell, watch

I'm trying to display the status progression of a file copied with dd command:
I run this command : `dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=1024 bs=10485760`

Then in another terminal, I run this command to display the status of progression:
`watch -n 1 kill -USR1 $pid_dd`

My problem I have tried to redirect the output of watch to a file but without success.

I have tried this solution proposed on this link [How to save output of "watch" to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849956/how-to-save-output-of-watch-to-file)

```
while true
do
   watch -n 1 kill -USR1 $pid_dd | tee -a output_watch.txt
   sleep 2
done
```

I don't know how to redirect the output of this command to a file. My solution doesn't work.

Comment: In your linked question it specifically states "You can try this without watch, if the exact 60 seconds is not an issue:" so sticking `watch` inside that loop is a bad idea. Just run your command `kill -USR1 $pid_dd` inside that loop with the pipe to `tee` without the `watch`. Essentially you don't want to print the output of `watch` to a file since it's mean to write to the screen and it's riddled with unprintable garbage to make that possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried that loop without the "watch" command, but the output file is empty :

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that loop above without the "watch" command like this :

```
while true
do
  kill -USR1 $pid_dd | tee -a output_watch.txt
  sleep 2
done
```

The problem is the "output_watch.txt" file is empty. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

`kill -USR1 $pid_dd` **doesn't output anything**. You have indeed successfully captured its output, which is empty. It sends a signal that causes the `dd` process -- an entirely different process -- to output progress data on *its* stderr, which you didn't redirect.

If you simply redirect `dd ... 2>&1 | tee -a file` it will make it more difficult to determine the PID of `dd` which you need. Depending on your shell consider instead

```
dd ... 2> >(tee -a file) & pid=$!

watch -n1 kill -USR1 $pid
# you don't need a loop around watch, it already _is_ a loop

# or _instead_
while kill -USR1 $pid; do sleep 1; done
```

Alternatively, see [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) which already does almost what you want (if available). Although described as monitoring the copying of data from one process to another, it actually does stdin to stdout which can (both) be files instead of piped processes.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly @dave_thompson ! It works, I have written this code :

```
dd ... 2>>/home/file.txt & pid_dd=$!
watch -n 1 kill -USR1 $pid_dd
```

The file "file.txt" has all information about the dd progress.

Thanks so much.